# Update from older GCC-based toolchain for which no source code is available

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm

Context: I am trying to update an ancient version of GCC to a newer one and there are only two or three puzzle pieces missing (it seems) to get it to work.

The old toolchain is configured as follows:

```
$ /opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/src/gcc-4.6-2012.03/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-arch=armv5te --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} %{funwind-tables|fno-unwind-tables|mabi=*|ffreestanding|nostdlib:;:-funwind-tables} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2012 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=3 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=57 %{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-lto --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-pkgversion='Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-57' --with-bugurl=https://support.codesourcery.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpc=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-ppl=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-libelf=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/obj/host-libs-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --disable-libgomp --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/nsidwell/arm/linux/install/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-57)
```

The ultimate goal is to build a (Linux) kernel with the updated toolchain. For now I am attempting to get `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` (from the Ubuntu 18.04 package `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`, version `4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3`) to do my bidding.

Trivial (hello world style) userland binaries built with that toolchain work like a charm. However, the kernel won't load and since the board for which this kernel is meant won't show a thing with the kernel built this way, I have no feedback as to what is wrong (as I would have with a `SIGILL` when running a userland binary containing "incompatible stuff". The (U-Boot) `mkimage` binary used is still the original one and its output is identical no matter whether I use the new or old toolchain to build `vmlinux`.

Now, so far I ended up using the following two flags, which I determined were used by the old toolchain, but for which the new toolchain had different defaults:

```
-march=armv5te -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd
```

The resulting `vmlinux` binary only differs in a handful of aspects and I think therein lies the problem that keeps the kernel from booting.

By way of `gcc -v -E - </dev/null` for each toolchain, I was able to boil down the list of differences in flags passed as well. However, some of the flags literally seem to have changed and I was unable to find a list of flags with how to migrate to their newer counterparts ...

Also it appears that the newer `readelf` packaged with `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` does not know of the flag 0x2 in `e_flags` (ELF header flags) which the older `readelf` calls "has entry point", difference:

```
-  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
+  Flags:                             0x5000002, Version5 EABI, <unknown>
```

I found no way of setting this flag, so far.

When comparing the properties of the two resulting `vmlinux` files, the differences are somewhat bigger, but seem manageable:

```
$ diff <(/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf -hA ../vmlinux-gcc-4) <(/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf -hA ../vmlinux-gcc-7)
--- /dev/fd/63  2019-09-25 16:25:22.056115611 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/62  2019-09-25 16:25:22.056115611 +0200
@@ -10,14 +10,14 @@
   Version:                           0x1
   Entry point address:               0xc0008000
   Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
-  Start of section headers:          3446116 (bytes into file)
-  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
+  Start of section headers:          4919528 (bytes into file)
+  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, <unknown>
   Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
   Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
   Number of program headers:         3
   Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
-  Number of section headers:         26
-  Section header string table index: 23
+  Number of section headers:         27
+  Section header string table index: 26
 Attribute Section: aeabi
 File Attributes
   Tag_CPU_name: "5TE"
@@ -30,4 +30,3 @@
   Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
   Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
   Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
-  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

The differences regarding the section headers are probably less relevant, if at all. But what stands out are the `e_flags` (picking the most readable output from the old and new `readelf`):

```
-  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
+  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
```

... and the file attributes:

```
-  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

The CPU I am targeting is this one (stripped for brevity):

```
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5
Hardware        : DaVinci DA850/OMAP-L138/AM18x EVM
```

So evidently the (old) toolchain used was a generic one.

For a comprehensive comparison of the outputs of `-Q --help=-target` for both toolchains with the newer one using `-march` and `-mcpu` to target the specific CPU model, i.e.:

- **old:** `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Q --help=target` versus
- **new:** `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv5tej -mcpu=arm926ej-s -Q --help=target`

... see this "table":

```
Option                        old         new
-falign-arrays                [disabled]  n/a
-mabi=                        [empty]     aapcs-linux
-mabort-on-noreturn           [disabled]  [disabled]
-mandroid                     [disabled]  [disabled]
-mapcs                        [disabled]  [disabled]
-mapcs-float                  [disabled]  n/a
-mapcs-frame                  [disabled]  [disabled]
-mapcs-reentrant              [disabled]  [disabled]
-mapcs-stack-check            [disabled]  [disabled]
-march=                       armv5te     armv5tej
-marm                         [enabled]   [enabled]
-masm-syntax-unified          n/a         [disabled]
-mbig-endian                  [disabled]  [disabled]
-mbionic                      [disabled]  [disabled]
-mcallee-super-interworking   [disabled]  [disabled]
-mcaller-super-interworking   [disabled]  [disabled]
-mcirrus-fix-invalid-insns    [disabled]  n/a
-mcmse                        n/a         [disabled]
-mcpu=                        [empty]     arm926ej-s
-mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd          [enabled]   [disabled]
-mflip-thumb                  n/a         [disabled]
-mfloat-abi=                  [empty]     soft
-mfp16-format=                [empty]     none
-mfp=                         [empty]     n/a
-mfpe                         [disabled]  n/a
-mfpe=                        [empty]     n/a
-mfpu=                        [empty]     vfp
-mglibc                       [enabled]   [enabled]
-mhard-float                  [disabled]  [empty]
-mlittle-endian               [enabled]   [enabled]
-mlong-calls                  [disabled]  [disabled]
-mmusl                        n/a         [disabled]
-mneon-for-64bits             n/a         [disabled]
-mpic-data-is-text-relative   n/a         [enabled]
-mpic-register=               [empty]     [empty]
-mpoke-function-name          [disabled]  [disabled]
-mprint-tune-info             n/a         [disabled]
-mpure-code                   n/a         [disabled]
-mrestrict-it                 n/a         [disabled]
-msched-prolog                [enabled]   [enabled]
-msingle-pic-base             [disabled]  [disabled]
-mslow-flash-data             n/a         [empty]
-msoft-float                  [disabled]  [empty]
-mstructure-size-boundary=    [empty]     8
-mthumb                       [disabled]  [disabled]
-mthumb-interwork             [enabled]   [disabled]
-mtls-dialect=                gnu         gnu
-mtp=                         [empty]     soft
-mtpcs-frame                  [disabled]  [disabled]
-mtpcs-leaf-frame             [disabled]  [disabled]
-mtune=                       [empty]     [default]
-muclibc                      [disabled]  [disabled]
-munaligned-access            [enabled]   [disabled]
-mvectorize-with-neon-double  n/a         [disabled]
-mvectorize-with-neon-quad    [disabled]  [enabled]
-mword-relocations            [disabled]  [disabled]
-mwords-little-endian         [disabled]  n/a
```

### Question

How can I coerce the modern (packaged) toolchain to

1. set the `Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed` (== value 1) *file attribute* **and** make sure the compiler doesn't emit `sdiv` and `udiv` instructions?
2. disable soft-float altogether and set the 0x2 ELF header flag ("has entry point")?

NB: I am happy to pass additional linker or assembler command line options *or* to build another object file from some potential pseudo opcodes which I haven't found so far, but which yield what I need. **What I would like to avoid is having to build a new toolchain** (I *know* how to do it, I have done it - both with `crosstool`/`crosstool-ng` and manually -, but it can quickly become maintenance hell) specific to that ARM CPU. Our modern toolchains are outfitted to target several CPU models, so I'd be hard-pressed to accept an answer suggesting this. Especially since I could easily write my own GCC specs file to imbue the proper command line arguments as defaults in my build process.

---

I've been partially successful with scouring the binutils source code and found the following line in the test suite for `gas`:

```
.eabi_attribute Tag_DIV_use, 1
```

And I was finally able to smuggle the `Tag_DIV_use` attribute into the object files. turned out that setting `.eabi_attribute` for `Tag_DIV_use` was indeed the way to convey to `ld` that I don't have support for these instructions. Unfortunately setting the attribute alone doesn't really seem keep the compiler from emitting these instructions.

The problem was, however, that some `.S` (assembly) files also included said global header and so the syntax (`asm("...")`) was incorrect `gas`' point of view. This could be fixed by checking for the define `__ASSEMBLY__` and either use the straight pseudo opcode *or* use the syntax acceptable to the C compiler.

```
#ifdef __ASSEMBLY__ /* from inside .S files */
    .eabi_attribute Tag_DIV_use,1
#else
    asm(".eabi_attribute Tag_DIV_use,1");
#endif
```

---

I was meanwhile able to find the source code (and the original download for the binary toolchain) created by CodeSourcery. Newer ones are also available:

- [arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2)
- [arm-2012.09-64-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2012.09-64-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2)
- [arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2013.05-24-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2)
- [arm-2013.11-33-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2013.11-33-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2)
- [arm-2014.05-29-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2014.05-29-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.src.tar.bz2)

... so that takes the pressure out of my endeavor. But I'd still like to be able to employ a modern (packaged) toolchain instead of some customized one.

Comment: Build Binutils, then GCC, then the GNU C Library, and build all your software and your kernel with the new toolchain.

Comment: @JL2210 thanks, but that's pretty much the scenario I wanted to avoid (I also gave a rationale as to why).

Comment: I don't think the older kernels work with recent GCC.

Comment: @JL2210 how so? Besides, the kernel I am attempting to build is 3.3.0 with some patches, so fairly old itself. Or did you mean the other way around? Indeed there was a header specific to major version 4 of GCC which I replaced by a newer one along with three (or so) others. But that took care of the issue that GCC 7 was "too new" for the old kernel ...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I had some issues with this when trying to build even 3.18 for my Chromebook.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70128  I don't get this.  You are saying that 4.6.3 and 4.7.4 are generating the same code?  It is possible, but it sounds rather amazing to me. It is also possible to configure linux with early debug and trace where the issue occurs.  It seems more of a maintenance issue to make gcc generate some identical binary to an old compiler to me.  I do understand wanting to know why things differ.

Comment: @artlessnoise where are you taking that 4.7.4 version number from? One GCC is 4.6.3, the other 7.4.0 (Linaro). But thanks for that reference. Didn't even come up when I looked for issues related to `Tag_DIV_use` during my web search.

Comment: Then 7.4.0 is even worse!  I read your 4:7-4.0 incorrectly (and it seem a more rational goal to me; 4.6.3 to 4.7.4 maybe possible).  The kernel pushes the compiler limits and when a new compiler is released, there is often fixes in either the compiler or the kernel to handle the new compiler.  You can not just update the compiler version by ensuring options are correct alone.  In *arch/arm* run `git log --grep='gcc' .` and you can see some of the changes.  You need back-ports of the gcc related changes when upgrading gcc.  Most changes are warning but at least 3-4 are boot or random crashes.

Comment: `git diff 208fae5c~1 208fae5c` and `git log 208fae5c` from mainline will give this idiv fix. There is some other issue with ip register use that I recall as well that might bite you. I think it was fixed in gcc though, so your Linaro gcc is probably taken care of that.  Your CPU doesn't have `idiv`, so you shouldn't be using this.  I don't know why you configured this way if you always have **ARM926EJ-S**?  Ie, *ARM_PATCH_IDIV* is false in your `.config`.  Maybe that is your answer to the **Tag_DIV_use**?

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks, I'll give that a try next week and let you know. Possible that this solves the problem alright. If so, then it'll turn out to be less of a compiler problem than a problem of the code being compiled. But likely still be educational. So you could _then_ write it up as an answer. Btw, I already surmised that the `idiv`/`udiv` is the issue, I just didn't know how to tell the compiler to get rid of it (or why the compiler would generate "faulty" code when told about the CPU model).

Comment: @artlessnoise I seem to be unlucky here. [ARM_PATCH_IDIV](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ARM_PATCH_IDIV.html) has only been "recently" introduced (kernel 4.5), while I am still stuck with the 3.3 kernel. However, this has given me some hope and I have meanwhile been able to find the source tarballs, which I will link from my question.